# Kotlin: How to get the value of a bit at a certain position from a Byte?

Tags: kotlin

I found solution for java:

```
public byte getBit(byte value, int position) {
   return (value >> position) & 1;
}
```

But how it is in Kotlin?

Comment: What is `ID`???

Comment: I edited code. (ID is source byte)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Kotlin equivalent is:

```
fun getBit(value: Int, position: Int): Int {
    return (value shr position) and 1;
}
```

Comment: Yep, just need convert Byte to Int for "shr" operation. Thanks